# Insufficient privileges Error in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created new lightining component for creating new project object through button in opportunity object.But for particular profile when i am log in as user i am getting insufficient privileges error. **I am getting error in Lightining component ui**

[image]

Where the Privileges are restricted for particular profile? I have checked with the project object and related fields in profile all they have access as Read

> But in Lightining UI Create project button is disabled

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a custom validation message. There's some existing customization in your org stopping this.

Comment: @DavidReed, I have checked custom error messages, but there is no custom error messages

Comment: @VinothBalasubramaniyan David is mentioning to check the validation rules on the appropriate object. The message seems to be a custom error message from a validation rule.

Comment: There is no error messages in validation rule of particular project

Comment: Did you check that particular user access rights for the project object? It looks like access rights issue but the error is probably custom.

Comment: I agree it is a custom error message. Check the object's triggers.